# Tikz externalize doesnt compile pdf when using \tikzset{external/mode=graphics if exists}

Tags: tikz-pgf, latexmk, tikz-external

Hellow there,

I have set up a minimal multifile example to see how the `\tikzexternalize` command works.
The file structure is as show below

```
|-main.tex
|-sec/
|--sec1.tex
|--sec2/tex
|-Graphs/
|--TikZ/
|---Sec1/
|----circle.tikz
|---Sec2/
|----square.tikz
```

the `main.tex` includes

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize
\tikzset{external/mode=graphics if exists}

\makeatletter
    \newcommand{\inputtikz}[1]{%
        \tikzsetnextfilename{#1}%
        \input{\tikzexternal@filenameprefix#1.tikz}%
    }%
\makeatother
\author{Author}
\title{Test}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\tikzsetexternalprefix{./Graphs/TikZ/Chap1/}
\input{sec/sec1.tex}


\tikzsetexternalprefix{./Graphs/TikZ/Chap2/}
\input{sec/sec2.tex}
\end{document}
```

`sec1.tex`

```
\section{First Section}
\begin{figure}[h!]
    \centering
    \inputtikz{circle}
    \caption{}
\end{figure}
```

`sec2.tex`

```
\section{Second Section}
\begin{figure}[h!]
    \centering
    \inputtikz{square}
    \caption{}
\end{figure}
```

`circle.tikz`

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0,0) circle (2cm);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

`square.tikz`

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0,0) rectangle (2,2);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

The document compiles just fine, but if the `\tikzset{external/mode=graphics if exists}` is enabled then the tikz figures aren't compiled in .pdf files. If I comment the `\tikzset...` the the tikz figures are compiled like the should but then the pdf files aren't included in the document.

I'm testing this because I'm writing my thesis and I have a lot of `.tikz` files and plots and the compilation takes a while.

I tried to compile the document without the new command or in different order of the tikz commands but the result is the same.
I'm using `latexmk` and Vim with vimtex plugin.

Are there any solutions to this?

Thanks in advance!